# Count the number of times a record appears and place in a bucket, SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder, reportbuilder3.0

More head banging for something that I'm sure is an easy solve.  I'm attempting to count the number of accounts that appear in a dataset more than once, but less than 6 times.  I can't even get the code to count the number of instances that accounts appear more than 2x's.

```
123
123
456 
456
111 
111 
111
```

I should be able to say that the above dataset based on my query = 3.  I want to count 123 as 1 instance, 456 as 1 instance and 111 as 1 instance since they all appear greater than or equal to 2 times.  After I figure this out, I should be able to get to the point where I can do my buckets.  But, I can't seem to breakthrough this part yet.

I have tried this, and it works, but doesn't give the result I want.  It gives me the number of records in the data set.

```
=IIF(count(Fields!AcctID.Value) >= 2, Count(Fields!Instance.Value),0)
```

I have also tried this, and it also gives me the same result as the code above:

```
=Count(IIF(Fields!AcctID.Value >= 2, Fields!Instance.Value,0))
```

Comment: can you explain the output type? means exactly what you want as output?

Comment: I'd like the output to = 3 in my report

Comment: You could do this in your query with windowing functions, or in either the query or SSRS by making using of grouping.

Comment: You have a sql tag on this question. Are you looking for a sql answer or a SSRS answer? This is pretty easy to do in sql.